# Facebook Like Extracting URL Data with Play Framework 2.x

Tags: jquery, facebook, scala, playframework

I would like to extract data from given URL like Facebook do.

I mean:

1. Put url to input field
2. Asynchronosuly (jQuery ?) load content from given URL like:

   - Title
   - Descripton
   - Images
3. Populate my view and store this information in NoSQL database like MongoDB

I want to use Play Framework 2.x and Scala to realize that task.
How can I achieve this? Any backend solutions?
Parsing OG tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Play uses netty's async library, you can do this fairly simply.

On the client side, you'll want to make a request (jQuery's `$.ajax` works if that's what you're familiar with) to your Play server. Your play server will asynchronously request the URL, and then parse the response.

```scala
case class ScrapedPage(title: String, desc: String, image: String)

def scrape(url: String) = Action {
  // Perhaps: check if you've already scraped this page from your db? If not:
  Async {
    WS.url(url).get().map { response =>
      val scrapedPage = parsePage(response.body)

      // Store this data into your database... then,

      Ok(
        Json.obj("title" -> scrapedPage.title, "desc" -> scrapedPage.desc, "image" -> scrapedPage.image)
      )
    }
  }  
}

def parsePage(body: String): ScrapedPage = ???
```

On the callback, your client can then populate this data into the UI in a useful way.

To store this data into a database, the implementation completely depends on what database / access layer you're using. This shouldn't be too complicated though.

As for parsing the page, you have several options. Check out [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/), which lets you use a [CSS/jQuery style selector syntax](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) to query the DOM. You can grab the title, meta tags, and images that way.